# Mqtt client only receives one message and sends one message and after that it does nothing

Tags: java, kotlin, mqtt, paho

I have been trying to get a connection to a mqtt server working for a while,
and while the subscription is received, it executes once and after that it only executes after a server restart

```
if (!mqttClient.isConnected){
    mqttClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions).waitForCompletion()
}
val iMqttToken = mqttClient.subscribe("devices/+/+", 0) { topic, message ->
    // gets printed once
    println(topic + String(message.payload))
    val pointTo = topic.substring(topic.indexOf("/") + 1, topic.length)
    val result = Math.random() > 0.5
    val publishTopic = "server/$pointTo"
    // gets printed once
    println("enviando respuesta a $publishTopic")
    // publish goes out and gets received by MQTT device
    mqttClient.publish(publishTopic,
        "{\"granted\":$result,\"transactionId\":21334}".encodeToByteArray(),
        0,
        false)
    Timer().schedule(2000) {
        // Prints true
        println(mqttClient.isConnected)
    }
}
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong any help is apreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kotlin, but don't you need to explicitly setup a `IMqttMessageListener` callback to handle incoming messages?

Comment: @hardillb It actually listens, the part where it has "topic, message ->" is the beginning of the definition for the lambda of *IMqttMessageListener*, its just that the message goes in 1 time, and then it acts as it stoped listening

Comment: Yes, but I can't see how that lamda is bound to the client, What's returned from the subscribe method call is a iMqttToken for the subscription.

Comment: I will close this as it ended up being a problem with my network provider, once I tried to use a local mqtt server everything was solved